# Set viewer's position and direction programmatically

Tags: 3d, aframe, webvr

I'm using A-Frame v3.6.0 and I'd like to set viewer's position and direction after a 3d object is clicked. I'm using this code to define camera and cursor elements:

```
<a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6" universal-controls position="0 -1 4">
    <a-entity cursor position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.020; radiusOuter: 0.028" material="color: #95E0E8; shader: flat"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

I've seen examples that use setAttribute calls to update position, but I don't know how to get the camera object, or how to set the direction vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can get A-Frame elements the same way you get HTML elements. Give it an ID, and select it by ID:
HTML: `<a-entity id="camera" camera="universal-controls">`
JS: `document.querySelector('#camera').setAttribute('position', {...})`

To change the direction, just use the `rotation` attribute. You can do your own math to get angles for a certain vector, but [look-at](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/look-at/) handles most of my use cases. There are also plenty of helpful math functions in THREE.

However, the position and rotation of the camera are often set automatically from the headset/device, so you should avoid relying on directly modifying the camera entity and instead modify a wrapper for the camera.

HTML:

```
<a-entity id="camera-wrapper">
    <a-entity id="camera" universal-controls>
        <a-entity cursor position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.020; radiusOuter: 0.028" material="color: #95E0E8; shader: flat"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
<a-entity>
```

JS: `document.querySelector('#camera-wrapper').setAttribute('position', {...})`

Comment: I tried to use a wrapper but that prevented JS from changing the value. Accessing the camera entity directly works for me, but only for the position attribute. Rotation attribute does not change: var cam = document.querySelector('#myCam'); cam.setAttribute('rotation', '0 45 0'); Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This kind of works: var other = document.querySelector('#otherObj'); cam.object3D.lookAt(other.object3D); But moving the mouse resets rotation (camera jumps to last known location set by the mouse movement). I guess that's what jbjw meant by "position and rotation of the camera are often set automatically". Is there a way to somehow coordinate UI rotation with programmatic rotation?

Comment: What if we wanted to just set x but not y or z?

Comment: @Ronk Here's an example of that: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-position-example